# Expo React-Native: Deep linking is not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Deep linking is not working on android when the app is on background or foreground state, but if it's closed it works perfectly fine. Only in android but in iOS it works both even if it's in background or closed app state.

I have these methods, but it doesn't work on android when it's on background or foreground

```
1. Linking.addEventListener('url', callback)
2. Linking.getInitialURL -- it returns a Promise that resolves to the url, if there is one.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, `Linking.addEventListener('url', callback)` returns and event, to get the url it should be `event.url`, what I did before is `Linking.addEventListener('url',(url) => setLink(url))` which must be `Linking.addEventListener('url',({ url }) => setLink(url))`.

Comment: Thank you SO much Michael, yours solution was the one that finally did the trick for us in SDK 40. For future readers, don't forget you must youse both Linking.addEventListener and Linking.getInitialURL, something like this: `componentDidMount = async () => { Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {this.handleUniversalLinkUrl(url); }); const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL(); if (initialUrl) { 
      this.handleUniversalLinkUrl(initialUrl);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Linking.canOpenURL(ValidateRedirectionData.responseDto.redirectUrl).then(
    (supported) => {
      console.log(supported, "sup--------------");

      Linking.openURL(ValidateRedirectionData.responseDto.redirectUrl);

      console.log("deeplinking2------------------------");
    }
  );
```

try like this