# How to Refresh Native Deeplink Application When In Foreground?

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I have a problem when I use deep linking android on react native. And when the application is in a foreground state when the application is triggered from deep-linking the application does not refresh on that screen. For example, I want deep linking to the Home Screen but when my foreground is on the profile screen then my application doesn't refresh?

this my code for deeplinking :

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    //  This for deeplinking
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
        this.navigate(url);
      });
    } else {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
```

```
  navigate = (url) => {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');
    const id = route.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
    const routeName = route.split('/')[0];
    if (id === 'yes') {
      alert(id)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why didn't you listen for url change in case of `android`?

Comment: Listen how? In the foreground the screen was not refreshed.

Comment: With android, it cannot register this listener `Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);`. You have `if` condition above.

Comment: Yeah, it conditions for iOS and Android. but I think that's not problem.

Comment: Or faster can you give me link or Have you ever experienced the same case with react native?

Comment: I haven't experienced this issue. But in the document `addEventListener` to listen for url change event. So I think you can receive something there. Here is doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#addeventlistener

Comment: My problem actually just simple, how to refresh the app to root app when the app in the foreground and refresh the app by deep linking?

Comment: If you'd like to execute a code when coming from background to foreground, you could use `AppState`. Here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/59388611/8268484

Comment: Yeah, I was trying AppState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use property from react native firebase, which can detect app in foreground, background nor in app. [documentation](http://%20https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage) if you used notification for your app. And if you not you can use **didFocus()** from react navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and this StackOverflow answer solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59351886/5901486

To quote Michael

> Finally I figured it out, Linking.addEventListener('url', callback) returns and event, to get the url it should be event.url, what I did before is Linking.addEventListener('url',(url) => setLink(url)) which must be Linking.addEventListener('url',({ url }) => setLink(url))